# MatLab find cells with specific values in two cell arrays

Tags: arrays, matlab, indexing, cell, cell-array

I want to find cells, which are at the same position in two different cell arrays and which have specific values.

The two cell arrays have the following structure:

cell array `C1= cell(20,1)`. In each cell there is another cell `cell(8129,8)` holding double values in the range of [0,1].

Cell array `C2= cell(20,1)`. In each cell there is another cell `cell(8192,8)` also holding double values in the range of [0,1].

I know want to find those cells, which (1) have a specific value that I determine (e.g. C1_value = 0.8 and C2_value = 0.85) and (2) are at the same position in the respective sub cell (!) array (e.g. C1{2}(736) == 0.8 and C2(19)(736) == 0.85). NOTE: The same position only refers to the subcell arrays (`cell(8192,8)`) not the "main" cell arrays `C1(:)` and `C2(:)`

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hint: http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html

Comment: So what must be the output for the sample case? `736`? Or `2` and `19`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this approach works for you -

```
sz = cell2mat(cellfun(@size,C1(1),'uni',0))
row1 = sz(1);
col1 = sz(2);

t1 = reshape(horzcat(C1{:}),row1,col1,[])
t2 = reshape(horzcat(C2{:}),row1,col1,[])

b1 = t1==C1_value
b2 = t2==C2_value

tt1 = reshape(b1,row1*col1,[])' %//'
tt2 = reshape(b2,row1*col1,[])' %//'

tt22 = permute(tt2,[3 2 1])
tt3 = bsxfun(@and,tt1,tt22)
[C1_cellnum,subcellnum,C2_cellnum] = ind2sub(size(tt3),find(tt3)) %// outputs
```

Thus, with your sample data, you must have -

`C1_cellnum` as `2`, `C2_cellnum` as `19` and `subcellnum` as `736`.

Comment: @PeterRussel Glad it worked for you, was really interesting problem and got me few insights about cell arrays myself, so thanks to your problem!